# Paypal IPN script is not working error 400-Bad request

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to create a subscription website. Everything is working fine except that the Paypal IPN script is not working. The log is showing a “400 - Bad request error”.The reason I found is that Paypal has made changes to its IPN script requirements. The new script is very different from the one I am using. I have tried everything but I am not able to get the IPN script working (both new and old). I searched everywhere and found a solution here: http://larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1577-chapter-6-ipn/&tab=comments#comment-9605  . But it is no more applicable since Paypal has made further changes to the script.) Could someone please update my IPN script so that it starts working again. Thank you very much for your help.

Below is my IPN script:

```
<?php


// Require the configuration before any PHP code as the configuration controls error reporting:
require ('./includes/config.inc.php');
// The config file also starts the session.

// Open the text file:
// The text file must be writable by PHP!
$file = fopen('./ipn.txt', 'a');

// Write the POST data to the file:
fwrite($file, "Received:\n");
fwrite($file, print_r($_POST, true));
fwrite($file, "\n");

// Start by creating a request variable:
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

// Add each received key=value pair to the request:
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Open a socket connection to PayPal:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Test
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Live

if (!$fp) { // If we couldn't connect, send an email:

    trigger_error('Could not connect for the IPN!');

} else { // Send the request to PayPal:

    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    // Write the PayPal request to the text file:
    fwrite($file, "Sent:\n");
    fwrite($file, "$header\n");
    fwrite($file, "$req\n");

    // Read in the response:
    while (!feof($fp)) {

        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        // Write the PayPal response to the text file:
        fwrite($file, "Received:\n");
        fwrite($file, "$res\n");

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

            // Check for the right values:
            if ( ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed')
             && ($_POST['receiver_email'] == 'seller_1281297018_biz@mac.com')
             && ($_POST['mc_gross'] == 10.00)
             && ($_POST['mc_currency']  == 'USD') 
             && (!empty($_POST['txn_id']))
            ) {

                // Need the database connection now:
                require(MYSQL);

                // Check for this transaction in the database:
                $txn_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['txn_id']);                
                $q = "SELECT id FROM orders WHERE transaction_id='$txn_id'";
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0) { // Add this new transaction:

                    $uid = (int) $_POST['custom'];
                    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['payment_status']);
                    $amount = (float) $_POST['mc_gross'];
                    $q = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id, transaction_id, payment_status, payment_amount) VALUES ($uid, '$txn_id', '$status', $amount)";
                    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
                    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {

                        // Update the users table:
                        $q = "UPDATE users SET date_expires = IF(date_expires > NOW(), ADDDATE(date_expires, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), date_modified=NOW() WHERE id=$uid";
                        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
                        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) != 1) {
                            trigger_error('The user\'s expiration date could not be updated!');
                        }

                    } else { // Problem inserting the order!
                        trigger_error('The transaction could not be stored in the orders table!');                      
                    }

                } // The order has already been stored!

            } // The right values don't exist in $_POST!

        } elseif (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
        }

    } // End of the WHILE loop.

    // Close the connection:
    fclose ($fp);

} // End of $fp IF-ELSE.

// Inidicate the end of this transaction in the text file:
fwrite($file, "--------------\n");
fclose($file);

?>
```